# Looping through items and waiting till all items has been checked before success Swift

Tags: swift

I have a forLoop which loops over items in a textField array and checks if the fields are all filled else return. The issue I have is by default, 3 of the 4 items in the array are pre filled so at first instance, the first item is the unfilled one and the function breaks but once I make the item in the second one empty too and fill the first one, it funs `true` first before rerunning the check which is `false` this how ever defeats the check. How can I prevent `true` closure from getting called till all items has been reviewed.

```
private func formArrayValidation(completion: @escaping (Bool, [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
        guard self.pageThree.formArray.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        for form in self.pageThree.formArray {
            
            guard form.textField.text != "" else {
                SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.dynamicModel?.name ?? "") is required", haptic: .error)
                completion(false, nil)
                break
            }
            
            guard Regex.validateDynamicForm(form.textField.text ?? "", pattern: form.dynamicModel?.pattern ?? "") else {
                SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.textField.text ?? "") does not match our pattern", haptic: .error)
                completion(false, nil)
                break
            }
            guard let key = form.dynamicModel?.key, let value = form.textField.text else { return }
            inputParameter[key] = value
            self.applicationParameter["inputs"] = inputParameter
            completion(true, applicationParameter)
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `completion(true)` line **after** the loop because **all** forms must pass the tests.

And replace `break` with `return` to return immediately

```
private func formArrayValidation(completion: @escaping (Bool, [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
    guard !self.pageThree.formArray.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    for form in self.pageThree.formArray {
        
        guard !form.textField.text.isEmpty else {
            SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.dynamicModel?.name ?? "") is required", haptic: .error)
            completion(false, nil)
            return
        }
        
        guard Regex.validateDynamicForm(form.textField.text ?? "", pattern: form.dynamicModel?.pattern ?? "") else {
            SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.textField.text ?? "") does not match our pattern", haptic: .error)
            completion(false, nil)
            return
        }
        guard let key = form.dynamicModel?.key, let value = form.textField.text else { return }
        inputParameter[key] = value
        self.applicationParameter["inputs"] = inputParameter
    }
    completion(true, applicationParameter)
    
}
```

Note: Check if collection types and strings are empty always with `isEmpty` rather than `count > 0` or `!= ""`

Comment: If it is called outside the loop, the check would always be true where `formArrayValidation` is used because after setting to false, it breaks out of the loop but still executes the end of the function @vadian

Comment: According to your code it's clearly called **inside** the loop and please see the edit to replace `break` with `return`

Comment: I have tried it and that was what happened. After you break from the loop, the `completion` outside the loop is executed.

Comment: control flow was the issue. Thank you @vadian

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the previous guys solution you can do the following:

```
private func formArrayValidation(completion: @escaping (Bool, [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
    var isValidated = false
    guard !self.pageThree.formArray.isEmpty else {
        completion(isValidated, nil)
        return
    }

    for form in self.pageThree.formArray {
        guard !form.textField.text.isEmpty else {
            SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.dynamicModel?.name ?? "") is required", haptic: .error)
            isValidated = false
            break
        }
        
        guard Regex.validateDynamicForm(form.textField.text ?? "", pattern: form.dynamicModel?.pattern ?? "") else {
            SPAlert.present(message: "\(form.textField.text ?? "") does not match our pattern", haptic: .error)
            isValidated = false
            break
        }

        guard let key = form.dynamicModel?.key, let value = form.textField.text else { 
        isValidated = false
        return
        }
        inputParameter[key] = value
        self.applicationParameter["inputs"] = inputParameter
        isValidated = true
    }

    completion(isValidated, applicationParameter)
    
}
```

Comment: This would fail because the first cycle of the loop would make isValidated true and defeat the purpose of the check. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Are you sure? We don't exit the loop until all the items in the array are finished. If we exit before hand at any point do to an error isValidated is set to false.